# Displaying current date through php

Tags: java, php, html, date, wamp

I'm a java developer & have been developing only in java for quite a long time.. now, a friend of mine had written a code in php which required to use a remote web-service  & pull a field "dateAdded". I have been given that code to modify and display current date rather than dateAdded.. I understand this might be a piece of cake but somehow I'm unable to bite it...

Below is the code snippet -

```
<?php
    // lines of php code...
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    $thisDate = date('m/d/Y');
?>

<?php           
    // some more lines of php script...
    <span class="job-info">Posted: <? echo $thisDate?></span>         
<?
```

I can't make any changes to this php code structure, it has to be like this 2 diff. blocks...

Now, when I run this code on localhost WAMP server.. it does not display any date...

I would really appreciate if someone can explain & share the code... Kindly consider, that I'm basically a server side programmer & not too much comfortable with client side scripting.

Thanks.

Comment: `PHP` is server side language. Also change `<?` to `<?php`.

Comment: check if `short tags` are enabled **OR** simply try `<?php echo $thisDate; ?>`

Comment: use this function to display date("D M j");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code.

```
<?php
             date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
                     $thisDate = date('m/d/Y');


             // some more lines of php script...
?>
             <span class="job-info">Posted: <?php echo $thisDate ?></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
<span class="job-info">Posted: <? echo $thisDate?></span>
```

to:

```
echo "<span class=\"job-info\">Posted: $thisDate</span>"
```

When writing HTML within a PHP block, you must use "echo"

You should read some tutorials at http://php.net/manual/en/introduction.php before asking questions here, you'll find a lot of answers there